# Objective-C: Copy images from file to device pasteboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, clipboard

I have an image file (.png) saved to the app's documents directory that I want users to be able to copy to the device pasteboard.  The goal here is to allow them to leave the application after they've copied the image and paste it somewhere outside of the app, such as a text message or email.

Here's what I've tried to copy the image to the UIPasteboard:

```
NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testscreen.png"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:convertedFilePath];
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteBoard.persistent = true;
[pasteBoard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```

I've tried a few variations on this as well, such as setting the 'image' property like the following:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteBoard.image = <someImg>
```

However, when I leave the application and attempt to paste what I've copied outside of the application, it acts as if I did not copy anything to the clipboard at all and pastes what I had previously copied.

If I want to allow users to copy an image to the clipboard and then leave my application and paste these images via Text or Email, is UIPasteboard the proper way of handling this?  I've seen this type of behavior in another application called [SMS Rage Faces](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sms-rage-faces-2200+-faces/id478755973?mt=8), so I know its possible to access the clipboard and copy an image to it that users can then paste where ever they please - but my images never seem to copy properly to the clipboard, or they are not persisting outside of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing wrong type inside the setData:forPasteboardType: method

You have to pass an UTI, that you can obtain from your file extension (assuming that the extension matches the real file type).
Do something like this:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

CFStringRef uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"png", NULL);

[pasteboard setData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:yourData] forPasteboardType:(__bridge NSString *)uti];

if (uti)
    CFRelease(uti);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this and was able to compile but still seeing the same issues as described above.  Just to double check, the yourData parameter in 'setData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:yourData]' should still be pointing to my file path, correct?  I have confirmed that the saved file on the device is named 'testscreen.png' and is being saved in the Documents directory  by using [DiskAid](http://www.digidna.net/diskaid) to ensure it properly exists.

Comment: I copied/pasted the code from one of my applications on the AppStore, and it's is possible to copy a png image and then paste in "messages", for example. Are you sure your NSData is ok and not null?

Comment: Yourdata should be NSData *yourData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:convertedFilePath];

Comment: Would I just need to pass yourData as such: [pasteboard setData:yourData ...]?  Declaring NSData *yourData as above and passing that in [pasteboard setData:...] is causing an issue since dataWithContentsOfFile is expecting an NSString but I'm passing NSData instead, unless I'm missing something.  I will try getting some debug info on my NSData and confirm if that is valid (I've been having issues pulling NSLog() data from my device after updating to iOS 7.1.2, so unfortunately I've had trouble confirming if things are being set correctly or not).

Comment: dataWithContentsOfFile: expects an NSString with the path of the file, not an NSData. For this reason I think that your NSData variable is nil. It's really simple to check in the simulator or on the device, using one breakpoint and the debugger (or simply the variable inspector in XCode)

Comment: Solved the debugging issues I was having - I had some compiler flags set incorrectly in Unity that was causing the issue and the function wasn't being called properly.  Once that issue was solved the above worked, thanks!